# Obtain user mail from facebook with polymer firebase-element

Tags: polymer-1.0

I am using the example provided with polymer here: [In the polymer documentation](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/firebase-element?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=firebase-collection)
Or directly from this example [x-login](https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/firebase-element/blob/master/demo/x-login.html)

but what I need now is to take the mail of the user in facebook for example, in the code in this part:

```
 <h3>User ID:</h3>
<pre>{{user.uid}}</pre>
```

they use the user.uid to obtain the ID from facebook but I want also the mail, and the name, but I can't get those :(, do you know how to do that?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are not using the "scope", in the optional third parameter of authWithOAuthPopup method.

```
ref.authWithOAuthPopup("facebook", function(error, authData) {
  if(error) {
    console.log("Esto es un Error", error.message);
  } else {
    console.log("Ok", authData);
  }
},{
  scope: 'email'
});
```

In the Facebook developers documentation you will find the diferent permissions you can ask for. Some of them you will need to validate your app in the app facebook dashboard.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions